# use reflection to get BatteryStatsHelper.getUsageList()

Tags: android

this is the code about use reflection to get BatteryStatsHelper.

```
 try {
        batteryStatsHelperClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsHelper");
        Constructor constructor = batteryStatsHelperClass.getConstructor(Context.class); 

        Method getUsageList = batteryStatsHelperClass.getDeclaredMethod("getUsageList");
        getUsageList.setAccessible(true); 

        List list = (List) getUsageList.invoke(batteryStatsHelper);
        Log.d(TAG, "size:  " + list.size());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

*the list I get is empty, I want to know this way is true, why I can't get the data ?*

this is the source code of BatteryStatshelper.

```
 public BatteryStatsHelper(Context context) {
    this(context, true);
}

public BatteryStatsHelper(Context context, boolean collectBatteryBroadcast) {
    this(context, collectBatteryBroadcast, checkWifiOnly(context));
}

public BatteryStatsHelper(Context context, boolean collectBatteryBroadcast, boolean wifiOnly) {
    mContext = context;
    mCollectBatteryBroadcast = collectBatteryBroadcast;
    mWifiOnly = wifiOnly;
}

 ..................

 public List<BatterySipper> getUsageList() {
    return mUsageList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must init the instance of an object first, like (You are not calling the `Constructor`):

```
BatteryStatsHelper helper = new BatteryStatsHelper(context, true);
helper.create(savedInstanceState);
```

Answer (score 0):

To properly call this Class, you need to create a new instance by declaring the Constructor and using it.

```
Object o = Class.forName("com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsHelper")
                .getConstructor(Context.class, boolean.class, boolean.class)
                .newInstance(getContext(), true, true);
```

But when I tried to use some of the methods, I was getting only dummy values.

```
double foo = (Double) Class.forName("com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsHelper")
                .getMethod("getComputedPower") // get method
                .invoke(o); // use it
```

> Output: "1.0"

I suppose this constructor needs a system Context. I don't know how to get it. If you know how, please let us know.

**Edit:**

I was able to use the [Android hidden API](https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api) to use some framework API's without using reflection. But i wasn't able to retrieve any value from the BatteryStatsHelper nor BatteryStatsImpl. 
The BatterySipper is an Object that save all data of an app, but you need to fill it.

I'm studying now the [settings app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/android-4.3.1_r1/src/com/android/settings/fuelgauge/PowerUsageSummary.java) inside the Android OS to understand how to properly call all those classes that was mentioned above.

Comment: HI , Have you figured it? I am also trying to get using Android_Hidden_api but not able to load the class name (com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsHelper).

Comment: No, I haven't figure out how to use those classes. Beside Hidden API and Java Reflection, Dagger may help in this situation as well.